# why bits sets are decreased after setting flag manipulator?

Tags: c++, flags, manipulators

#### 1

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
int main()
{
    
    std::ios_base::fmtflags flag=std::ios::showpos;
    
    std::cout<<std::cout.flags()<<"\n";
    std::cout<<flag<<"\n";

    std::cout.flags(flag);
    std::cout<<std::cout.flags()<<"\n";
    
    std::cout<<59.20<<"\n";

    std::cout<<std::bitset<16>(4098)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<std::bitset<16>(2048)<<"\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
4098
2048
+2048
+59.2
0001000000000010
0000100000000000
```

see here I set `showpos` flag manipulator and then I value returned by `cout.flags()` (current format setting) decreased bits set.

#### 2

**Code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
int main()
{
    
    std::cout<<std::cout.flags()<<"\n";
    
    std::cout<<std::showpos;
    std::cout<<std::cout.flags()<<"\n";
    
    std::cout<<59.20<<"\n";

    std::cout<<std::bitset<16>(4098)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<std::bitset<16>(6146)<<"\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
4098
+6146
+59.2
0001000000000010
0001100000000010
```

here as expected bits set value increased by `1` as I added one flag manipulator.

Why when I set flag with help of `cout.flags()` function bit sets decrease rather than increase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`flags` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) takes the new value, not a flag to add. What you're doing is replacing the flags entirely with `showpos`.

If you want to do it with `flags`, you need to add the flag yourself:

```
std::cout.flags(std::cout.flags() | std::ios::showpos);
```

Comment: first of all thanks. Now  I get cleared concept. also can I use `std::cout.setf(flag)` right ? and another thing I don't understand `std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex , std::ios::basefield);` often I see such statements. what this comma `,` signifies between flag manipulators and what's purpose of this statement.

Comment: @AbhishekMane, Yes, you can confirm it in the [`setf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) documentation; `std::cout.setf(flag)` will add `flag` to the set flags. You can also see there's an overload that takes a mask. Since the comma is top-level in a function call, it's separating the arguments. The overload lets you replace the ones covered by the mask while leaving all the flags not covered by the mask untouched. So here `dec` and `oct` would be cleared and `hex` set because `basefield` encompasses those three and `hex` is the new value given.

Comment: thanks,  I got this too. I have another doubt [in this code](https://ideone.com/PGcxMf)  I used  `std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex | std::ios::dec | std::ios::oct);` might be this is wrong to use, I don't know. but I just checked it. bits set increased by `2`  and no change in output. so even it is changing bits set still output is not changing and why it is increasing bits set by `2` if it have to it should be increased by `3` or using such things leads to `Undefined behavior` ?

Comment: what is mask you mentioned ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane, `dec` is already the default, so you only see the other two added. With more than one active, `dec` wins and output is in base 10. As for the mask, bitmasking in general is used to select only some bits. For example, `flags & std::ios::basefield` would give you only the bits corresponding to the three base flags. In the version of `setf` that takes two arguments, the second is named `mask` in order to signify that only the bits that are set in the mask can be changed.